# Passenger SecurityUpdateChecker Error

Tags: passenger

In `passenger.log` such error occurs:

> 2018-02-24 11:13:03.6657 1536/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:362 ]: 
>       Security update check failed: Couldn't connect to server for 
>       https://securitycheck.phusionpassenger.com:443/v1/check.json 
>       (if this error persists check your connection security or try upgrading Passenger) 
>       (next check in 24 hours)

Please help how to investigate and solve this.